# JQuery - Repeat similar buttons

Tags: jquery, button, repeat

I need to open page_i_j when menu_i_j is pressed , but i and j are not fixed values.

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
            $('#menu_page_'+$i+'_'+$j+'').click(function(){
            if($('#page_'+$i+'_'+$j+'').is(':hidden')){
                 $('#page_'+$i+'_'+$j+'').fadeIn(200);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

html/php of button[#menu_page_i_j](a little messy,sorry):

```
for($i=1;$i<=$menu_quant;$i++) {
                echo '
                    <a href="#"><div class="menu">
                        <div class="menu_title">
                            '.${'menu_title_'.$i}.'
                        </div>
                        <a href="">
                        <div class="menu_options">
                            ';for($j=1;$j<=${'menu_options_'.$j.'_quant'};$j++) {
                                echo '<a href="#?m='.$i.'&s='.$j.'"><font color="#1d70b3"><div id="menu_page_'.$i.'_'.$j.'"class="menu_options_hover">'.${'menu_options_' .$i. '_' .$j}.'</div></font><br></a>';
                                }echo '
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div></a>';
                    }
```

Comment: can you show your html markup as well.. and where is your for loop..?

Comment: sounds Tabs thing, you can check how others do for tabs or accordion, like jquery ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the values of `i` and `j` to set the handler. You can use a single selector:

```
$("[id*='button_i'][id*='_j']").click(function(e) {
    var selector = '#page' + e.target.id.slice(e.target.id.indexOf('_'));
    if($(selector).is(':hidden')){
        $(selector).fadeIn(200);   
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2tJh/) that demonstrates how to add the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would to this, first, add a class to those menu items, something like "class='menu_button'", then do:

```
$('.menu_button').on('click',function(){
  id = this.id.replace('button','page');
  if ($('#'+id).is(':hidden')) $('#'+id).fadeIn(200)
})
```

that's much cleaner, maybe you don't even need a class, something like "$('#menu a')" could work if all your links are anchors inside an element with id 'menu'

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu_options').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(':hidden')) {
        $this.fadeIn(200);
    } 
});
```

This is a far better better solution performance wise. You attach the handler to the parent element and it catches the event when it bubbles up.